# Howto use multiple " within a href?

Tags: html

I want to make something like this [drag bookmarket to your browser](http://delicious.com/tools#title0) in order to perform a javascript.

I got so far with the code:

```
<a class="bookmarklet" title="KB Fjernadgang" 
href="javascript:(function(){a=window;parts=window.location.href.split(\"/\");parts[2]+=\".ep.fjernadgang.kb.dk\";url= parts.join(\"/\");a.open(url,\"bkmk_popup\");})();"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3216968/Billeder/KB%20Fjernadgang.png" alt="KB Fjernadgang"></a>
```

Had to remove all "var" with spaces because it was being converted into %20. But I seem to have a problem with the multiple " now. It only makes a bookmark with this code

```
   javascript:(function(){a=window;parts=window.location.href.split(\
```

The escape character '\' did not seem to do the job.. How do I escape "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the double quote characters in the attribute value as `&quot;`. This is called a *character reference* in HTML.

Alternatively, you could just replace them with single quote characters: `'`.

Comment: Of course :D Just had to wait 9 minutes until stackoverflow would allow me to accept your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Switch to `'`. The XML parser is only looking for a `"` and not testing if it's been escaped inside a javascript call.

Comment: Yup. Whenever you write inline JS like that, use one string delimiter around the JS and the other inside the JS.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the `href` attribute. Set it to `href="#"`.

Use `onclick` instead: `onclick="bookmark();"` then write the js logic:

`function bookmark(){ your bookmark logic comes here }`

Comment: It's a bookmarklet. The whole point is that the browser treats the JavaScript as a URI (so it can be added to the bookmarks). Using `onclick` or moving the code to an external function would defeat the object. If using `onclick` and a function would fix it, then `href="#"` would be terrible as it isn't [progressive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement). Using an `onclick` *attribute* wouldn't be very good either as it isn't [unobtrusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a URI, escape it as `%22`.

(`&quot;` is if you were escaping it for HTML, but you are putting it in a URI then putting that URI in HTML, so you should use URI escaping before worrying about HTML escaping).